# Keep default store selected in Store switcher in Admin

Tags: admin, magento2.3, store-view, store-switcher

I have created custom grids in Admin and given store switcher by XML file as below.

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<head>
    <title>Products</title>
</head>
<update handle="styles"/>
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="page.main.actions">
        <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Store\Switcher" name="products.store.switcher" template="Magento_Backend::store/switcher.phtml"/>
    </referenceContainer>       
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <uiComponent name="products_listing"/>
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
```

How can I keep my default store as selected on the page load?

Also I have 4 websites and each have 1 store. on the grid listing page default store view should be selected and display for example US.

When i go record edit I have to display store switcher there to. And in this store switcher only display website and store which belongs to that product. Currently from list page I select the store and go to any product of that store then it's displaying selected store but in dropdown displaying all the websites and stores even product is only for 2 stores.

Answer (score 1):

**Try This :-**

```
<referenceContainer name="page.main.actions">
        <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Store\Switcher" name="adminhtml.report.shopcart.abandoned.store_switcher">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="switch_websites" xsi:type="string">1</argument>
                <argument name="switch_store_groups" xsi:type="string">1</argument>
                <argument name="switch_store_views" xsi:type="string">1</argument>
                <argument name="use_confirm" xsi:type="string">0</argument>
                <argument name="default_selection_name" xsi:type="string" translate="true">All Websites</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </referenceContainer>
```

Comment: Tried this but Not working

Comment: change param value 1 to 0 and check

Comment: It's also not working

Comment: check updated answer

Comment: By that code nothing is displaying. I have 4 websites and each have 1 store. on the grid listing page default store view should be selected and display for example US.

When i go record edit I have to display store switcher there to. And in this strore switcher only display website and store which belongs to that product. Currently from list page I select the store that go to any product of that store it's displaying selected store but in dropdown displaying all the websites and stores even product is only for 2 stores.